# Magento 2 - core/resource_transaction

Tags: magento2

I have the following Magento 1 code and I would like to know the Magento 2 equivalent of the code.

I've looked around on the web but unable to find a proper solution.

```
Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below way is equivallent of magento 1 to magento 2,

```
 <?php
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Transaction $transactionFactory
    ) {
        $this->_transactionFactory = $transactionFactory;       
    }
```

After declared as above use inside funtion,

```
$invoice = "Your Custom Object";
$this->_transactionFactory->addObject($invoice);
```

Remove var folder from root and check,

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
     * TransactionFactory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\DB\TransactionFactory
     */
 protected $_transactionFactory;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\DB\TransactionFactory $transactionFactory
) {
    $this->_transactionFactory = $transactionFactory;
}
```

// now you can use this like,

```
$saveTransaction = $this->_transactionFactory->create();

$saveTransaction->addObject('YOUR_OBJECT_1');
$saveTransaction->addObject('YOUR_OBJECT_2');
$saveTransaction->save();
```

you can also use `delete()` method If you want instead of `save()`